# Allow a login form from website to sign into my Rails 5 app using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5 and Devise.

I want to put a login form with email and password on a website (www.abc.com) that's not within the Rails app (www.xyz.com).

I put the form one www.abc.com with a POST to www.xyz.com. Of course now I get an error because of the missing auth token (protect_from_forgery).

To avoid this I can put `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` in my session controller. But I was wondering if there are better ways to do this.

Has Devise some native functionality for this?
How can I allow protect_from_forgery with: :null_session only for requests from www.abc.com?

Answer (score 0):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html

Something along the lines of

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session,
                     if: -> { request.domain.include?("abc.com") }
```